# How to use vue-multiselect tagging inside asp .net solution using VS 2017?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vue.js, vue-multiselect

I'm trying to use vue-multiselect tagging, but im getting some errors like:

"vue.js:634 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option."

And:

"SyntaxError: The requested module 'https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.1.0' does not provide an export named 'default'"

Can Anyone helps me?

my script:

```
    <script type="module">
    import Multiselect from 'https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.1.0'

    export default {
        components: {
            Multiselect
        },
        data() {
            return {
                value: [
                    { name: 'Javascript', code: 'js' }
                ],
                options: [
                    { name: 'Vue.js', code: 'vu' },
                    { name: 'Javascript', code: 'js' },
                    { name: 'Open Source', code: 'os' }
                ]
            }
        },
        methods: {
            addTag(newTag) {
                const tag = {
                    name: newTag,
                    code: newTag.substring(0, 2) + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000000))
                }
                this.options.push(tag)
                this.value.push(tag)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

my html code:

```
                <div>
                    <label class="typo__label">Tagging</label>
                    <multiselect v-model="value" tag-placeholder="Add this as new tag" placeholder="Search or add a tag" label="name" track-by="code" :options="options" :multiple="true" :taggable="true"></multiselect>
                    <pre class="language-json"><code>{{ value  }}</code></pre>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First include the files:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.0.6"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.0.6/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css">
```

Then, register the component:

```
components: {
    Multiselect: window.VueMultiselect.default
},
```

I found the solution here:

https://github.com/shentao/vue-multiselect/issues/643

Answer (score 0):

I think using a custom control like vue-multiselect with support for tagging is what you are looking for. See [here](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-tagging).

Comment: This is what im looking for. I'm trying to do the multiselect Tagging but i'm getting the errors: [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <multiselect> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

Comment: and the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module 'https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.1.0' does not provide an export named 'default'

Comment: This is to do with how you are setting up your app. I think you need to look at the docs. You are trying to use the component without actually registering it with due first and so due does not know what you are talking about "Multiselect" and throws error. See https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-getting-started. Also please accept the answer if I addressed your original question.

Answer (score 0):

To render the list of "Exporters" you must set the select options to be dynamic. According to the Vue.js docs you need to do something like:

```
<select v-model="selected_exporter">
  <option v-for="exporter in exporters" v-bind:value="exporter.value">
    {{ exporter.description }}
  </option>
</select>
<span>Selected: {{ selected_exporter }}</span>
```

Then you want to put a input if the exporter does not exists yet, you can use the `v-if` to show or hide the input.